# Use of rational and irrational coordinate systems

Tags: real-numbers, coordinate-systems, rational-numbers

Why are the coordinate axis on most of the graphs always irrational? That is why don't we usually use coordinate axis which is devised on rational numbers?

My friend stated that its because most lines such as $y=e$ cannot be plotted on a rational grid system. But that cannot be true since $e$ does have a rational number summation ($2+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{7}{100}...$) which can be utilised to plot $y=e$ on the rational coordinate system.

So why don't we use rational number coordinate system?

P.S. By irrational grid system I mean a grid in which $\pi,e$ can be plotted.

Comment: Do you really mean "real" instead of "irrational"? And no, the graph of $e^x$ has very few points with rational coordinates. An infinite sum of ever decreasing rational numbers is not necessarily rational. Also, in a rational coordinate system, graphs that look like they should intersect one another don't always intersect. For instance, the horizontal line $y = 2$ and the parabola $y = x^2$ wouldn't intersect in a rational coordinate system.

Comment: "the coordinate axis on a standard graph always irrational" Why so ? On a standard graphh we have "points" at $1,2$ etc.

Comment: @Arthur Yes that was basically my argument with my friend. But shouldn't we be able to see the intersection if we were to zoom infinitely (take the limit)?

Comment: @FaiqRaees The graphs clearly cross (the parabola is above, then below, then above the line as you move to the right). However, the rational coordinate system doesn't contain the exact point at which it happens. Taking the limit doesn't play nicely with rational numbers. The real numbers are usually constructed explicitly to make limits work the way they intuitively should, and that is done in order to avoid exactly this kind of counterintuitive results (there are many other reasons to use the real numbers, but in calculus and analysis, that's the only reason that really matters).

Comment: @Arthur Thank you that was very helpful. Can you please give an example of "taking the limit doesnt play nicely with rational numbers"? I cant see how it wont work. If possible can you also state the other reasons or maybe give me some resource so I can find it out myself?

Comment: For instance, the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$, which is clearly bounded and increasing, so it _should_ converge to some number. Also, for any finite $n$, the sum is clearly a rational number, since it's the sum of finitely many fractions with integers in numerator and denominator. However, the limit is $e$, which is not rational. Another example: take the sequence $$3, 3.1, 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415,\ldots$$All these numbers are rational, since the decimal expansion terminates. However, they converge to $\pi$, which is not rational.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Thank you very much. Can you also provide some other reasons or give me a source so I can learn about them from there?

Comment: Any decent introductory text in calculus or real analysis should bring up this point.

Comment: I checked 2-3 books but none of them answered the matter in hand. Can you please cite one of them?

Answer (score 0):

It’s all a question of scale, my friend!

[image: base 10]
[image: base pi]

As you can see, some graphs use incrementation in multiples of rational numbers, while others use incrementation in multiples of irrational numbers.

Either way, irrational numbers can be plotted on both. You might even use a mix, such as an increment for every integer multiple of $1$ as well as an increment for every integer multiple of $\pi$ (or $e$ if you’re into that)!